# How to create a horizontal scroll bar when shrinking the window

Tags: html, css

If I have a content area with a width of 1225px how do I make it so that when you shrink the page to less than that width a horizontal scroll bar appears so that that center content will always be visible (at least have the option for scrolling)?  Would it involve using fixed or absolute positioning?

In this site, you can see when you shrink the page, the horizontal scroll bar appears:  http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/

I don't know if it helps, but here is some of my code:

```
<body class="fullbackground">
    <img class="fullbackground" src="background.png" />
    <div class="topbackground">
            <div class="top">
                <div class="topleft">
                    <img class="pf_logo" src="pathfinder_logo.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="topmiddle">
                    <h1 class="title">Pathfinder is Temporarily Unavailable</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="topright" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div style="width:1225px; height:870px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
        <div class="contentcontainer">
```

I used a CSS reset.  Here is some of my CSS:

```
.bar {
    background-color:#365C8C;
    height:30px;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    overflow-x:hidden; 
}

body {
    position:relative;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ADCCEB;
    /*background-color:black;*/
    /*background: url(background.png);*
    /*background-size:100%;*/
}

.bold {
    font-weight:bold;
}

.contentcontainer {
    width:825px;
    height:870px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    /*background-color:red;*/
}

.extcontentcontainer {
    width:825px;
    height:645px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    /*background-color:red;*/
}

img.fullbackground {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

img.extfullbackground {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try adding this property to the body tag:

overflow-x:auto;

Comment: That worked, but now my image is shrinking when I shrink the width, so I can see a strip of the background color for the body on the right side of the page (#ADCCEB)

Comment: That's because you applied a width:100% to the img tag, try removing that property and replace it with a width in pixels.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

`<div style="width:1225px; height:870px; padding-top:0px; margin-top:0px; overflow-x: scroll;">`

`overflow` property should give you your scroll bar.